# Android Google Map v2 signed apk doesn't work

Tags: android, google-maps, sha1, api-key

Yet another question on GoogleMaps Api Key and release mode.

I have my API key, correctly added the SHA-1 in the allowed Android Applications, copied the key in the manifest and the same in both google_maps_api.xml (debug, release) in Android Studio.
In debug everything works fine, but when I install the app through the Signed Apk it shows me gray screen and google logo.
Anyone knows what I can do about that?
Any help would be much appreciated.
This is my AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Welcome"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".GalleryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_gallery"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TripActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_trip"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PromoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_promo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contact"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the map in xml code like this:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

also implement map in java?

```
GoogleMap googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
googleMap.getUiSettings();
googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
```

There is more info about Google Maps [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/)

Also if you have any question just ask

**Update:**

This part of the code:

```
  <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

needs to implemented right after the activity of the class where the map is located/

For example if the map is located in Welcome class the the manifest should look like this:

```
<permission
    android:name="com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:name=".app.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Welcome"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MenuActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".GalleryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_gallery"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TripActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_trip"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PromoActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_promo"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ContactActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_contact"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
```

**Update**

Check if you have updated google play services in android sdk and also check in gradle if you have added this line in `dependencies` :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
```

Comment: In xml and Java I have the same code but using SupportMapFragment

Comment: I posted my AndroidManifest until .ContactActivity just because the map is located in that Activity.
At the last, after that code I have another activity which implement Maps but this configuration works fine in debug mode.
I thought my issue was caused by uncorrect SHA or ApiKey but checked few times and it's correct.
A month ago I tried to generate the Signed APK for the first time and had to correctly setup the SHA1. From that moment I have not changed anything but today it doesn't work again.
My api key is active.

Comment: I had play-services: 6.5xxxx
Now updating sdk, I let you know

Comment: Unfortunately no. Tried with a new apiKey too

Answer (score 0):

I think you generated SHA fingerprint key from machine A and compiled your android project in machine B. That's one of reason you may get blank screen. Please build your android project in machine A.

Comment: Generated and compiled from the same machine

Answer (score 0):

I think that you miss `google play services`. You need to have it in order to use `Google Maps API v.2` You can get it from [here](http://www.teamandroid.com/gapps/) or [here](https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145).

Comment: It works in debug mode on the smartphone.
I've got the problem when installing through Signed Apk

Comment: That's because `google play services` is already installed in smartphone. So, if you use `Genymotion`, go download this from the given hyperlink and simply drag and drop it to your emulator

Answer (score 0):

I have just same issue and i know why.

Check the logcat if you find:

```
Google Maps Android API: Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start for how to correctly set up the map.
Google Maps Android API: In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
Google Maps Android API: Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
Google Maps Android API: Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
Google Maps Android API:       API Key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
Google Maps Android API:       Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx;com.example
```

Check file `google_maps_api.xml` in folder

app\src\**debug**\res\valuess
and
app\src\**release**\res\values

For debug is another file with API that in release.